# split a string and covert to float

Tags: split

I have the following string variable:

tail = ih_m10p0

I want to split this variable, convert 'm' to '-' and also convert 'p' to '.' and end up with a new float variable:

tail_new = -10.0

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself in a language you have not identified?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do this in python

Comment: What about the `"ih_"`?

Comment: I am not interested in the 'ih_'. Essentially, the variable 'tail' is the return from an os.path.split .. I want to extract the numerical part of that folder

Comment: What parts of this string will be the same no matter what you get from `os.path.split`?

Comment: I have the following, it works, but I wan wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it:

Answer (score 0):

I have following so far, it works, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this:

```
tail = ih_m10p0
t = tail.split("p")
t1 = t[0].split("_")[-1]

if "m" in t1:
   t2 = t1.split("m")[-1]
   tail_new = -1*float(t2)
else:
   t2 = t1.split(" ")[-1]
   tail_new = float(t2)
```